# Link ID in wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, slug

Currently I am working on a wordpress website, but I stumbled upon a little problem.

I am using `wp_page_menu` to make a navbar to get to my other pages. Now it directs me to `www.mysite.com/sport`, but I need it to direct me to `www.mysite.com/sport#header` or `www.mysite.com/sport/#header`.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I tried using different plugins, or changing the slug or permalink, but this didn't give me the result I wanted.

Thanks for helping guys!

Comment: Do you need it on all of the links, or just a single link?

Comment: @Stewartside On all links a different one would be the best, but on all links the same could work too

Comment: Why not just make a custom menu in the Admin? Rather than using a function to get the pages, you can manually link to them using the "Link" menu item type...Sounds easier than the alternative.

Comment: @rnevius I was hoping to avoid that.. Well, if there isn't really anything I could do about it, than I think I should go with a custom menu..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Here is your code. I just override default walker of wordpress. Please focus on text #header in this code.

If you worry about this code. So you can go to file: ...wp-includes/post-template.php at line 1238. It same code but I have add #header after get_permalink().

Hope that help.

```
 class WPSE_HasHeader_Custom_Walker extends Walker_Page {


        function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {

            if ( $depth )
                $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            else
                $indent = '';

            extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
            $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);

            if( isset( $args['pages_with_children'][ $page->ID ] ) )
                $css_class[] = 'page_item_has_children';

            if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
                $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
                if ( in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
                if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
                elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            }

            $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

            if ( '' === $page->post_title )
                $page->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $page->ID );

            /** CHANGE LINK HERE **/
            $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '#header">' . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';

            if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
                if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
                    $time = $page->post_modified;
                else
                    $time = $page->post_date;

                $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
            }
        }
    }

    wp_list_pages(array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'title_li'    => '',
        'echo'        => 1,
        'walker' => new WPSE_HasHeader_Custom_Walker()
    ));
```

Updated:

The second way:
Thanks Mere Development. I thinks this is same idea with him but it much more simple in your case. Like this:

```
$link = wp_list_pages(array(
                        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                        'title_li'    => '',
                        'echo'        => 0,
                    ));
echo preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"]*)"(.*)>/', '<a$1href="$2#header"$3>', $link);
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know `wp_page_menu` could use a Walker, it's not documented. yet.

Answer (score 2):

Christian's answer is great, and it got me thinking about alternative ways to do this, especially ones that allow you to use your `wp_page_menu()` function as originally requested. So here's another approach using a filter.

Add this function before your `wp_page_menu()` call, or in functions.php

```
function wp_list_pages_addhash($output) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($output);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
      $link->setAttribute('href', $link->getAttribute('href') . '#header');
    }
    $output = $dom->saveHTML();
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'wp_list_pages_addhash');
```

Then use your wp_page_menu call as you were originally in your theme:

```
wp_page_menu();
```

**Explanation:** It finds every href attribute of every link in the output of `wp_list_pages` and adds '#header' to the end. `wp_page_menu` in turn uses `wp_list_pages` to create output.